# When an app is uninstalled, is its SharedPreferences database cleared?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

When an app is uninstalled, is the data in its SharedPreferences database deleted?

If not, without a device being rooted, is there any way to clear that data?  (Or at least view it?)

Comment: SharedPreferences is located in the data directory of the app which gets deleted during uninstallation. Do you have a case where it was not deleted by the system?

Comment: @Firelord I was reading up on Stack Overflow on how to make an app with a "trial period".  One of the answers recommended writing data to SharedPreferences, because they claimed it can remain when an app is uninstalled.  That doesn't match what I remembered, so I thought it best to ask.

Comment: SharedPreferences are backed by Google if the app participates in the backup. It would be best  if you clarify whether "they" assumed your app would be backed up.

Comment: @Firelord I don't back up anything to Google (well, not intentionally), so I'm looking up what you're referring to.  I see a "Back up my data" option deep within Android Settings... is that it?

Comment: You are facing this problem. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup. As I suspected app data by-default gets backed up including SharedPreferences unless developer explicitly declines participation in the backup using a flag in app manifest. Full reading is recommended. Afterwards, related questions can solve your query: https://www.google.com/search?q=SharedPreferences+app+uninstallation+data&oq=SharedPreferences+app+uninstallation+data+&aqs=chrome..69i57.8562j0j4&client=ms-unknown&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Firelord Thanks.  Reading it now.

Comment: If auto backup is the issue, then you can clear the app data after reinstalling to delete all the shared preferences.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you.  You read my mind.  That's exactly what I was wondering. :)

Answer (score 6):

SharedPreferences are actually saved in a file in the app private directory:
`/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/somefilename.xml`

When an app is installed this directory and file are automatically created. When an app is uninstalled this directory is deleted along with its parent `/data/data/package_name` **UNLESS** the app is uninstalled in order to update it.
From command line this is done using the flag -k or -r that is

`adb uninstall -k package_name`  - Keep the data and cache direct­ories around after removal

`adb install -r package_name`  - Replace existing application (effectively reinstall an existing app, keeping its data)

Answer (score 5):

SharedPreferences database always deleted when app is uninstalled. But when in the AndroidManifest.xml `allowBackup` is set `true` then data is not cleared even if application is uninstalled and re-installed.

`android:allowBackup="true"`

So, always keep `allowBackup` to `false` when you don't want the data to be stored.

Comment: Thank you.  What is the best way to keep allowBackup as false?

Comment: @user298642 The allowBackup flag usually only affects the `adb backup`. Do you have a source that backs your answer?